# How to Un-install/re-install sails

Tags: 14.04

I want to reinstall sails because its not working properly for creating a new project and lifting the previous projects.

I have tried `sudo apt-get remove sails`but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it using this method:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/getting-started/getting-started.md

you will need to use the npm package manager to remove it.

try `sudo npm -g uninstall sails`

Comment: That's a separate issue to how to uninstall sails. You should make and post a new question about it on stack overflow, the programming questions website.

If this answer did successfully uninstall sails for you, make sure you accept it, so other people know it works!

Comment: Thats make unbuid but after reinstall sails having same problems.

installtion procedure:
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ sudo npm -g install sails


when i run $ sails new projectTest
           $ cd projectTest    
bash: cd: projectTest: No such file or directory